Inserting JSONB of a variable into table with Psycopg2 (Python to Postgres)
My task is to get JSON-Data from pokeapi and put it in a table on a pg4e-server (postgres for everybody) with psycopg2.
It works despite I am not able to put the JSON-data from python into the JSONB column of the table on the server. I've tried several approaches, but I need your support.
How can I take the JSON saved in a variable (text) and store it into the table?
Thank you very much in advance
My code:
Imports...

conn...
cur...



sql = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id INTEGER, body JSONB);
'''
print(sql)
cur.execute(sql)

url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1'

print('=== Url is', url)

response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text
print('=== Text is', text) 
text = json.loads(text)

sql = f'Insert into pokeapi (id, body) Values (1, 'text'::JSONB);'
cur.execute(sql, (text, url))

conn.commit()

cur.close()

Response:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id INTEGER, body JSONB);

=== Url is https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1
=== Text is {"abilities":[{"ability":{"name":"overgrow","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/65/"}....

 line 43
    sql = f'Insert into pokeapi (id, body) Values (1, 'text'::JSONB);'
                                                       ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


This question is similar to: Insert JSON data from REST API into PostgreSQL table using Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


DO NOT use f strings, use Parameter Passing. 2) Use the built in JSON adaptation that comes with psycopg2. 3) Read my answer to this question Insert JSON data from REST API into PostgreSQL table using Python


Thank you for your suggestions Adrian Klaver. I have tried your sollutions but I could't make it work. The sollution from Kirill Ilichev worked for me. There is the possibility that a more experienced programmer than me would find your solutions better.

All you need to do is: from psycopg2.extras import Json and then: cur.execute(sql, (1, Json(text_json))).

Thanks Adrian Klaver for your engagement. I wasn't able to pull that out of your link. I think I will stay with the solution which was more self-explanatory.

You are getting syntax error due improper string formatting, also you trying to insert JSON using variable.
Here is correct code that should work:
sql = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pokeapi (id INTEGER, body JSONB);
'''
cur.execute(sql)
url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1'
response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text
text_json = json.loads(text)
sql = 'INSERT INTO pokeapi (id, body) VALUES (%s, %s::JSONB);'
cur.execute(sql, (1, json.dumps(text_json)))

conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()

As you can see I used %s as placeholder for params, and passed it values as tuple in cur.execute()
Also I converted text_json back to json string by json.dumps()

Thank you very much. I am not sure if it worked. There ist no Error anymore but if I look at my body column, it seems empty?

Could you please provide output of this code:
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM pokeapi;'); rows = cur.fetchall(); for row in rows: print(row)

Thank you very much! Here is the output: (1, {'id': 1, 'name': 'bulbasaur', 'cries': {'latest': 'raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/cries/main/cries/pokemon/…). Everything works.


Why not use the JSON adapter that comes with psycopg2? 2) Why not use json_resp = response.json()?


I don't know unfortunately. I think I am not experienced enough to answer that. Why is it bad to stay with the solution from Ilichev?
